# Cmake add directory without source files

Tags: c++, cmake, directory, assets, clion

How can I add a directory with files that aren't source files? Do I have to define it like a source directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake doesn't care whether a directory contains source files or something else. A directory added by `add_subdirectory()` must contain a `CMakeLists.txt` file, but that's the only requirement. What the code in that subdirectory's CMakeList does is entirely up to you.